# Why does Eclipse report BUILD FAILED when Ant Tomcat task seems to be successful?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ant

When running Ant targets with tomcat manager commands they appear to be successful, but report BUILD FAILED.

Here are the relevant parts of my build.xml:

```
<property name="path"     value="/MyApp"/>

<property name="manager-url" value="http://localhost:8080/manager/html"/>
<property name="username" value="admin"/>
<property name="password" value=""/>

<taskdef name="start"     classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask"/>
<taskdef name="stop"      classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask"/>
<taskdef name="undeploy"  classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask"/>

<target name="start" description="Start web application">
    <start url="${manager-url}" username="${username}" password="${password}" path="${path}" output="${tomcat-home}/webapps/start.html"/>
</target>

<target name="stop" description="Stop web application">
    <stop url="${manager-url}" username="${username}" password="${password}" path="${path}" output="${tomcat-home}/webapps/stop.html"/>
</target>

<target name="undeploy" description="Start web application">
    <undeploy url="${manager-url}" username="${username}" password="${password}" path="${path}" output="${tomcat-home}/webapps/undeploy.html"/>
</target>
```

When I run these targets (start, stop, undeploy) from eclipse I get output like the following:

```
Buildfile: C:\eclipse_3.5\eclipse\workspace\MyApp\build.xml
Trying to override old definition of datatype resources
undeploy:

BUILD FAILED
C:\eclipse_3.5\eclipse\workspace\MyApp\build.xml:85: <html>

Total time: 20 seconds
```

the output redirected by the targets are html files that indicate that the Tomcat manager command was successful, and when I check the manager it seems like it was.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and discovered the answer [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200509.mbox/%3CC72BB9D74FA9874AA289B79F37A138A42FD727@inhywexcu1.ssainternal.net%3E)

The problem is the URL that you're using for the undeploy task; you need to remove the html.

```
<property name="manager-url" value="http://localhost:8080/manager/html"/>
```

should be:

```
<property name="manager-url" value="http://localhost:8080/manager"/>
```

Comment: I think the `/html` is needed iff you're using version 7.0 of Tomcat, otherwise the build fails to connect.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is probably unrelated to the undeploy invocation.

At line 85 you have a `<html>` tag which ant dislikes and cause the failure.

Comment: The <html> tag is not in my build.xml. It is in the html that is returned by the undeploy invocation. As you see, I've redirected the output to a file called undeploy.html. I'll paste it's contents here:

http://pastebin.com/shrxYk7v

As you can see the html file is a snapshot of the state of the manager page with this message at the top:

OK - Undeployed application at context path /MyApp

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer. Do NOT do what it says in the docs! The docs for the auto generated build.xml say to copy the catalina-ant.jar to the ant lib dir. THAT IS WHAT IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM! Remove it and whola, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your URL to

```
<property name="manager-url" value="http://localhost:8080/manager/text"/>
```

You may also need to add a new user to Tomcat's `conf/tomcat_users.xml`, because it's recommended to keep `manager-gui` (HTML access) separate from `manager-script` (text access):

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="browser" password="xyzzy" roles="manager-gui"/>
<user username="ant" password="plugh" roles="manager-script"/>
```

See also https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50706